# Have there been any fatalities caused by octopi?

Tags: history, zoology, oceanography

To what extent are octopi violent towards humans? Has there been any confirmed fatalities? [The source of all knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_attack) claims that some have the capacity to kill humans, and claims there have been documented instances of attacks but doesn't list any sources.

I found [this wiki.answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Has_a_octopus_ever_harmed_a_human) claiming humans have been poisoned by octopi. Also I'm interested if the altercation was provoked

Comment: if you eat a live one they can get stuck in your throat and suffocate you

Comment: People can die from choking while eating [sannakji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannakji). Those would technically count as fatalities caused by octopuses; but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're asking. Wikipedia cites [a Korean news article](http://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=sec&sid1=102&oid=001&aid=0001931575) reporting a person who choked from the dish (he was saved by medical personnel). The article also seems to mention another incident where a person died from the dish, but it may be just the bad translation by Google.

Answer (score 11):

The question about the *extent* of [octopuses](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/octopus) being violent is off-topic here.

Have octopuses have fatally envenomated humans?

Yes. In 1954, [Kirk Dyson-Holland](http://museumvictoria.com.au/about/mv-blog/nov-2011/death-by-octopus/) was killed after picking up ([what was later identified](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00852988.1964.10673804?journalCode=tmos19#.UyT2dvmSx8E) as) a blue-ringed octopus. Another man died in 1962.

In Australia, octopus attacks are [rarely seen in hospitals](http://www.wemjournal.org/article/S1080-6032%2802%2970605-4/abstract) and [rarely cause deaths in scuba-divers](http://archive.rubicon-foundation.org/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/9295/SPUMS_V20N1_2.pdf?sequence=1).

School children in Australia are now warned against them, which may explain the lack of reports in the last 50 years.